# Zip Module Not loading PHP 8.0.12

Tags: php

I am having an issue installing PHPOffice/PHPSpreadsheet on my production server using composer.  When I run `composer install` or `composer update` I get the following

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.19.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.19.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.19.0 requires ext-zip * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-bcmath.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sodium.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sqlite3.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xml.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-pdo_sqlite.ini
    - /etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
bash-4.2$ composer install --with-all-dependencies


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--with-all-dependencies" option does not exist.


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I am running PHP 8.0, and when I installed it I installed php-zip
When I run `php -m`  I get the following list

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

I have tried everything I could possibly think of to enable the zip extension.  I've even tried installing it again using `sudo yum install php-zip` and then attempting to enable it.

I installed my PHP stack using the following:
`sudo yum -y install php php-{cli,fpm,mysqlnd,zip,devel,gd,mbstring,curl,xml,pear,bcmath,json}`
after PHP was installed, I ran `php -m` and saw that the zip module was not loaded.  I then ran `sudo yum -y php-zip` viewed the loaded modules again, and it still was not there.  I then modified the php.ini file and added `extension=php`.  After I ran `php -v` and I received this message
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zip' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 8.0.12 (cli) (built: Oct 19 2021 10:34:32) ( NTS gcc x86_64 )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

This is the full list of commands I used to install PHP 8.  I followed the directions from the this website: https://www.tecmint.com/install-php-8-on-centos/

here are the commands I used

```
sudo yum install -y https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
sudo yum -y install yum-utils
sudo yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php80
sudo yum -y install php php-{cli,fpm,mysqlnd,zip,devel,gd,mbstring,curl,xml,pear,bcmath,json}
```

Does anybody have any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: How did you try to enable that extension? That hasn't worked properly until `php -m` lists the extension. And until then, this question is not related to Composer or any package you want to install using Composer

Comment: Also, you should not use `composer require` on your production server. Run this on a local machine, and deploy the resulting `composer.lock` to the production server. Use only `composer install` during deployment

Comment: I tried adding ```extension=zip``` to the ```php.ini``` file. I get an error when I reload apache that it cannot find the zip file in any location. From what I have read, PHP now automatically loads modules in the php.d directory, which the zip module is not in there either..

Comment: If the module isn't listed there, you haven't installed it properly. Please share more details about the installation. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Updated with as much information as I have.

Comment: Which version of `php-zip` did you install through yum? Is that package compatible with PHP 8? For example, on Ubuntu, you could install extensions for various PHP versions

Comment: how did you install php8? ppa? official repo (of what distro)? compile from source? the page that leads you to the php installation should list how to enable extension

Comment: I have updated the initial question with the commands and site I took the model from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to get the zip extension to load by installing the pecl zip module

`sudo yum install php-pecl-zip`  Once it installed and I reloaded apache running `php -m` showed

```
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Comment: Basically if you run `sudo yum install php-zip` it will install `php-pecl-zip`

Comment: I had tried `sudo yum install php-zip` but when I tested and checked after running it, it never installed.  I had to install it by specifying `pecl`.  `sudo yum install php-pecl-zip`  Once I ran that command it finally installed and loaded.